# Query that counts people that have met two separate criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I need to find a way to count the number of voters that live in the same house and that have voted ‘DEMO’, ‘REP’ or ‘DEMO-REP’.  I have gotten this so far, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/469d4/3

For instance, miles and Raquel live in the same house and have both voted ‘REP’, they would be counted in the ‘REP’ column. Chris and Tania both live in the same house and have voted ‘REP’ and ‘DEMO’ so they will go in the ‘DEMO-REP’ column. 
The fiddle result need to be.

[1 http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/3305/resultbx.png](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/3305/resultbx.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure I understand. It looks like you have 11 votes from 7 different households, but have only accounted for 4. Do you not want to return results at all for households that only voted once?

Comment: yes, in the real query I will want to return results for households that only voted once, I just left that part out for this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select sum(votes) as total, sum(demo*(1-rep)) as demoonly,
       sum(rep*(1-demo)) as reponly, sum(demo*rep) as demorep
from (select address, cont(*) as votes,
             max(case when voted = 'DEMO' then 1 else 0 end) as demo,
             max(case when voted = 'REP' then 1 else 0 end) as rep
      from t
      group by address
     ) t
```

Assuming you want households (addresses) with more than one person:

```
select sum(votes) as total, sum(demo*(1-rep)) as demoonly,
       sum(rep*(1-demo)) as reponly, sum(demo*rep) as demorep
from (select address, count(*) as votes,
             max(case when voted = 'DEMO' then 1 else 0 end) as demo,
             max(case when voted = 'REP' then 1 else 0 end) as rep
      from test4
      group by address
      having count(distinct name) > 1
     ) t
```

Here, I assume that "address" is a proxy for household, since there is no household field in the data.

Comment: I don't think that will give the correct result, I made it work for the fiddle here, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/469d4/23. Thanks

Comment: Did you fix the query?  I think you clarified the question after I answered.

Comment: No, it still isn't fixed, Thanks

Comment: I need more clarification.  If you want only households that voted once, how can you have both democratic and republican votes?

Comment: I am sorry, I think there is some confusion, If the addresses match, the household should be treated as one. There can be both democratic and republican votes because a husband and wife may have voted differently, but live at the same address. Thanks

Comment: How do you get the values 11, 2, 1, and 1 in your example?  (I understand the 11.)  These don't seem to correspond to your descriptions of them.

Comment: The result should only contain households with more than one address,and only one value per household.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This works with your SQL Fiddle code.

I would to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Voted) AS TOTAL, 
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT address) FROM test4
WHERE address NOT IN (SELECT address FROM test4 WHERE Voted = 'REP')
) AS Demo, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT address) FROM test4
WHERE address NOT IN (SELECT address FROM test4 WHERE Voted = 'DEMO')
) AS Rep,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT address) FROM test4
WHERE address IN (SELECT address FROM test4 WHERE Voted = 'REP') AND address IN (SELECT address FROM test4 WHERE Voted = 'DEMO')
) AS DemoRep
  FROM test4
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a HouseholdID in the table, Thanks

Comment: If you substitute "Address" for "HouseholdID" it should work just as well.

Comment: I am sorry I think there is some confusion, If the addresses match, the household should be treated as one and the only households should show up in the result. Thanks